# autoformat multi-line comment to single line intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have code contains single line comments on variables(intentionally).

```
  /** The object mapper. */
  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

But when I autoformat(ctrl+alt+l) it changes the single line comment to multi-line which I don't want.

I checked with the setting of Intellij but there is no such option.

Answer (score 1):

After investigation i find the solution for intellij

**Setting->editor->code style->java->java doc->others (tick donot wrap one line comments)**