# How to make Intellij generate one-line comment for field instead of multi-lines?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, live-templates

When I Alt+Enter on `private static final String FOO = "foo";` and select "Add Javadoc",
Intellij(version 2020.2) generate a multi-lines style comment like this.

```
    /**
     * blabla
     */
    private static final String FOO = "foo";
```

How do I make it generate one-line style comment instead?

```
    /** blabla */
    private static final String FOO = "foo";
```

Comment: Here is answer to your question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095023/autoformat-multi-line-comment-to-single-line-intellij)

Comment: @AzamatAminov No, this just prevents Intellij from auto-format one-line comment into multi-lines. What I want is generate one-line comment. Even when "Do not wrap one line comments" is checked, Intellij still generate multi-lines comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to modify the formatting of the "Add Javadoc" intention AFAIK. You can just type the comment instead, since it's just a few characters. Or you can create a Live Template (`Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`), to reduce the number of characters that is needed to type further. The Live Template could look something like this, for example:

```
/** $END$ */
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around idea. I bind "/" to your Live Template and it works well.